# Excel solve using cell formula without Solver

Tags: excel, math, optimization, excel-formula, logic

XX YY and ZZ are based on user input and are sum of respective rows. The sum of col T , col U and col V is as given and should not change. It is like a dynamic calculator to solve for values a1, a2, a3....c3 when given user inputs of XX, YY and ZZ. How can this be solved using just excel cell formula and no solver/goal seek/array/matrix/VBA. Thank

Comment: It isn't (usually) possible to solve this uniquely: you have 9 unknowns but only 6 relationships (3 rows and 3 columns). It is straightforward to come up with an algorithm to find one possible solution, but is that what you want?

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for your response. I dont want algo but want to solve some way in excel only. Also, this is one of the brain teaser question I found, so seems there is a solution for it that I don't know of. Also, I think there are 7 relationship (7th one is the last column sum)

Comment: But are you seeking all possible solutions, or just a single solution at random?

Comment: Hi Jos, single solution

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments, there might be more solutions but this is what I came up with. I named the E5 cell "TotalSum" for more readability.

[image]

The formula for B2:

```
=B$5/TotalSum*$E2
```

Simply expand right and down.

**Updated solution for whole numbers, if that is what you want:**

[image]

formula for B2:

```
=ROUND($E2/TotalSum*B$5,0)
```

Only expand right one column and down one row!

Formula for B4: `=B5-B2-B3`, expand right one column.

Formula for D2: `=E2-B2-C2`, expand down 2 rows.

**Explanation:**
What you are doing here is dividing numbers into 3 parts.
These parts need to have certain sums and certain ratios between them.
It's the correct ratio that will ensure that both the rows and columns will be the correct sums.

Take the first row: We know that the sum for the first row needs to be 50. In order to make sure the columns will add up correctly as well, we divide the desired sum for the current column by 300. This results in 0.55 for T column (165/300) so 55% of the 50 needs to be there. 165/300*50 = 27.5 The remaining columns are solved the same way so that the row adds up to 50, because 165/300 + 110/300 + 25/300 = **1**. 1 * 50 = 50

Why does this assure the column will add up to 165 as well? You can reorder the numbers to get: 50 / 300 * 165. Going down the column, the fractions 50/300 + 20/300 + 230/300 also add up to 1. 1*165 = 165

I'm not sure if I'm explaining this well. Probably not :( If you have more questions feel free to ask, I will do my best to explain further.

Comment: Thanks, what is the rationale/logic, could you please help elaborate

Comment: @user12838762 I edited the answer and added some explanation. I'm not best at teaching and explaining things unfortunately. If you have more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: @user12838762 I changed the explanation a bit and added another paragraph if you are interested. I feel like this could be explained in an easier and more understandable fashion by someone who actually knows about math and teaching but this is the best I can do x)

Comment: If there is an additional condition that the values of cell B2, C2 and D2 cannot be the same and likewise for other rows too. Similarly, the values of B2, B3 and B4 cannot be same and likewise for other columns, how to factor in this limiting condition ?

Comment: @user12838762 sorry but this is beyond my capabilities. The solution might be simple but I just don't see it at the moment. I think it should be possible though.